# Magento 2 - Cannot pass readiness check (Component Dependency)

Tags: magento2, composer, component-manager

I'm having a fight with the readiness check at the moment.
The only error I have to fix is the one below but I have no clue at the moment.

Please assist if you can.

```
Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: 
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed 
Failed to enable crypto 
failed to open stream: operation failed 


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Currently running: TLS 1.2 with ssl 3.1
Cannot change this due to shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to disable the TLS by editing the composer.json and adding:

```
"config": {
    "disable-tls": true,
    "secure-http": false
}
```

This is a solution that works for shared webhosters.